# Is it possible to convert an int to a string in C without sprintf?

Tags: c

I need to make code that makes array of `char` from an `int` like this:

```
int a = 312419;
string = ['+','3','1','2','4','1','9']
```

Another example:

```
int a = -20;
string = ['-', '2', '0']
```

I'm only allowed to use:

- `<stdio.h>` (but not the `*printf()` family of functions)
- `<stdlib.h>`
- `<string.h>`
- and `for` loops

Comment: If you want help with your homework, please edit your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to. Otherwise your question is liable to be closed, since it isn't at all clear what you are actually having trouble with here.

Comment: Yes.. it is possible.

Comment: Hint: Google how to extract different digits from a number and put those into a string.

Comment: Don't forget to add a null byte `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages now, and remember that we don't write the code for you, but we will help you fix an honest attempt to solve your problem.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), too.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "yes, it's possible"

I will however not do all your homework for you so here is some code that doesn't solve the whole problem but should give you an idea for solving the problem yourself.

```
  int a = 312419;
  while(a)
  {
    int t = a % 10;
    char c = '0' + t;
    printf("%c\n", c);
    a = a / 10;
  }
```

Output:

```
9
1
4
2
1
3
```

Notice how the number is printed in reverse order. Instead of doing that, your task is to save the chars in an array in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `snprintf` for that.

```
int a = -20;
char string[MAXLEN+1];
snprintf(string, MAXLEN, "%d", a)
```

The only difference is that you will get a `\0` value at the end of `string` array.

Comment: i can't its the mission

Comment: You've mentioned in your question that you are allowed to use `stdio.h` which is where `snprintf` is declared.

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz In the question it is mentioned - _"......converting int to string code in C without sprintf?"_